# Is there an IDE for Java that allows form making?

Tags: c#, java, forms, ide

I used Microsoft Visual Studio C# and that allowed us to make windows forms with a drag and drop feature where buttons, radio buttons, and textboxes and etc. can be dragged and dropped. Is there something like this for Java?

Comment: like java applets ?  Gnome? what are you targeting

Comment: Did you not would to have more control over the code?

Comment: There might be D&D GUI designers for Swing, but until you understand the Java layout-managers, they will produce crappy GUIs.

Comment: @AndrewThompson My only regret is that I can not up-vote the comment but once ... :(

Comment: Java Applets is what I am targeting. Like a full scale Java application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course there is:

1) NetBeans [GUI builder](https://netbeans.org/features/java/swing.html)

2) Eclipse with [Windowbuilder Pro](https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/wbpro/quick_start)
plugin installed

Answer (score 1):

[Netbeans](http://www.netbeans.org) has a "Design View" that functions as a drag-and-drop form editor. When you create any type of container - JFrame, JPanel, J/Applet, etc - there is a tab on the top of the screen that allows you to switch between Design and Source view.

Answer (score 1):

There is an IntelliJIDEA, a GUI Designer: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/gui_builder.html